# Copying formula from one row above in excel

Tags: excel

I am new to excel and I am hoping if someone could help me with this challenge.

What I am trying to achieve is use a continuation formula from cell above if the cell to the left of current cell is not empty.

As you can see in the attached picture, the formula is copied down the row but the left cell is empty, I only want excel to apply formula if left cell is not empty,

I will really appreciate if you can help me please.

[image: An example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISBLANK and IF function together to check whether a cell is blank or not and give the value you want.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "", <put your original formula here>)
```

It is checking whether cell A1 is blank, then give nothing if it is true. If it is false (there is something in the cell), it will evaluate 3rd argument. So put your formula there.
You may want to look at some beginners tutorial first so that you can learn more about excel functions systematically.

check 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2 and 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665
to know more the IF adn ISBLANK function

Comment: Thank You so much, it worked perfectly, appreciate it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `=ISBLANK()` to reliably test if a cell is actually empty.

The following is a table showing the results of applying various functions to a cell to test if is blank or is empty.

[image: Different formulas testing for empty cell]

Column H contains the actual values being tested. Column I shows what is actually in the cells in column H. Columns D:G apply various formulas to test the contents of H.

Note that, somewhat a misnomer, `=ISBLANK` is the reliable way to test for an empty cell. `=COUNTBLANK or IF(CELL.Value = "")`  are good ways to test for a blank cell.

I expanded on the example given by Colin Legg [here](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/is-your-cell-blank-or-empty/)

I hope i have used the term NullString appropriately,other users please feel free to correct me on that.

Comment: Awesome tip, thank you so much, really appreciate your answer and input, thanks you